# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, null

I know this error is very common but I can't find a solution..
This is a piece of my code: With this code I add the blur effect to three UIImageViews

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurview = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurview.frame = self.blurbar.bounds
    self.blurbar?.addSubview(blurview)

    let blurEffect2 = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurview2 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect2)
    blurview2.frame = self.home_tessera.bounds
    self.home_tessera?.addSubview(blurview2)


    let blurEffect3 = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurview3 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect3)
    blurview3.frame = self.blurbar2.bounds. **THE ERROR IS HERE: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**
    self.blurbar2?.addSubview(blurview3)
```

if I delete all the code from `blurEffect3` to `self.blurbar2?.addSubview...` the error goes into `blurview2.frame = self.home_tessera.bounds`. I have checked all the outlets but the error is still here.

Comment: I think,Your blurbar2 outlet is missing. So when use that property crash your app.

Comment: *Verify* your assumptions with `print(self.blurbar2)`  ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since `home_tessera` and `blurbar2` are optional, make sure they're not `nil`:

```
if let tessera = self.home_tessera {
    let blurEffect2 = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurview2 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect2)
    blurview2.frame = tessera.bounds
    tessera.addSubview(blurview2)
}

if let bbar2 = self.blurbar2 {
    let blurEffect3 = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
    let blurview3 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect3)
    blurview3.frame = bbar2.bounds
    bbar2.addSubview(blurview3)
}
```

You could have an `else` to catch the case where `home_tessera` and `blurbar2` are nil:

```
if let tessera = self.home_tessera {
//...
} else {
//print("home_tessera is nil")
}
```

Or use [optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) if you don't want to catch that case:

```
blurview2.frame = self.home_tessera?.bounds
//...
blurview3.frame = self.blurbar2?.bounds
```

Comment: A missing connection is a *programming error* and should not be swept under the carpet.

Comment: @xXManuelXx This only prevents the crash. It does not fix the actual problem.